# Check for root freezes

Tags: android, root

I'm creating an application, but now in time to check for root it freezes every single time i press "check for root" button. Any ideas?

here is the "check for root" code:

```
Process p;
        try {
            // Perform SU to get root privileges
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes("remount rw");
            os.writeBytes("echo Root Test > /system/rootcheck.txt");
            os.writeBytes("exit\n");
            os.flush();

            try {
                p.waitFor();
                    if (p.exitValue() != 255){
                        //Phone is rooted
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your device is rooted\r\n\r\n(Long Press to know how to get root acess)", 0).show();
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        //Phone is not rooted
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your device is not rooted\r\n\r\n(Long Press to know how to get root acess)", 0).show();
                        break;
                    }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
```

Comment: 'whoami' will return the user name, you don't have to remount and write to the filesystem (two potentially costly operations compared to just running a single command) to check if you did get root, just compare it's output against "root".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `waitFor()`  "Causes the calling thread to wait for the native process associated with this object to finish executing." per [SDK](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) specs.  It is looking like the `su` command never completes due to lack of root access.

Perhaps you may simply want to use `wait(long ms)` (documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29)) for a reasonable period of time, and test to see if your process completed successfully (have root) or timed out (do not have root).